# the app always shows no internet connection despite of internet connectivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My news app shows the message of no internet connection 
but there is internet  connection 
it always shows the nocontent message in if condition every time ....

i don't know the error source as the code seems correct to me ....

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                News currentNews = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                Uri newsUri = Uri.parse(currentNews.getmUrl());
                Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, newsUri);
                startActivity(websiteIntent);
            }
        });
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
            loaderManager.initLoader(0, null, this);
        } else {
            View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_bar);
            loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mbarTextView.setText(R.string.nointernet);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<News>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {return new NewsLoader(this); }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<News>> loader, List<News> news) {
        View loadingBar = findViewById(R.id.loading_bar);
        loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mbarTextView.setText(R.string.nocontent);
        mAdapter.clear();

        if (news != null && !news.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(news);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<News>> loader) {
        mAdapter.clear();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the Internet and Access_Network_State permissions in your manifest?

Comment: yes the manifest has the permissions